# Godox X1T(F) + V850ii on Fuji XE-3: does TTL mode work?

Tags: godox, ttl, fuji

I've borrowed a Godox X1T for Fuji cameras, and a Godox V850ii flash. I'm trying to use that stuff with a Fuji XE-3. I'd like to be able to do this in a "TTL" auto-flash setup, which I *think* should be possible. So far, the configuration user interfaces on the trigger and the flash itself have me utterly confused, and the Godox documentation has not cleared anything up.

I can get the trigger to fire the flash; I've got them on the same channel and the same group (which took a little while to figure out). So I have the camera in "TTL" flash mode, and the X1T on the "A" group also in TTL mode (I think; it says "TTL" next to "A" in the LCD). On the V850 I really can't tell what I'm supposed to do; it's on the right channel and group because it does fire, but it's vastly too much light for the test pictures I'm trying; they're just completely washed out as if the TTL mode isn't doing anything.

The camera is in aperture priority and auto-ISO. The V850 documentation doesn't mention anything about TTL support, and nor does its inscrutable UI, so maybe that's the problem, but I was led to believe that this setup *should* work. Maybe that was incorrect however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. To have TTL, all three links in the chain: the camera, the triggering system, and the flash have to be able to communicate TTL. The Godox TT600, V850 II, and (unfortunately) the V850 III are single-pin manual speedlights and cannot do TTL.

You'd need one of the following TTL-capable Godox speedlights to have off-camera TTL over radio with the X1T-F:

- TT350-F
- V350-F
- TT685 (any version, but firmware updated to "speak" Fuji if it's the Canon, Nikon, or Sony version)
- V860 II (ditto with the firmware)
- TT685 II (any version)
- V860 III (any version)
- V1 (any version)

Comment: Thanks, after staring at the Godox documentation for a long time I pretty much concluded what you're saying. Thank you very much.